# Can't decode JWT Token using @react-oauth/google | 'Invalid Token Specified'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, google-oauth

I want to decode the JWT token, but when I try to decode, it says (in promise) 'Invalid token specified'.

I know that when I retrieve the { tokens }, on res.json, it shows me on console the access*token, refreshtoken, and id* token, but I want to decode only the JWT Token, that is the id_token

My React Component

```
import { useGoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Button, Text } from '@radix-ui/themes'
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'


function Login() {

  const googleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
      onSuccess: async codeResponse => {
        console.log(codeResponse)
        const tokens = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/auth/google', {
          code: codeResponse.code,
        })
        var decoded = jwt_decode(tokens)
        console.log(decoded)
        /* console.log(tokens); */
      },
      onError: () => {
        console.log('Google Auth Failed!')
      },  
      flow: 'auth-code',
      scope: 'openid profile email',
/*       ux_mode: 'redirect',
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:5173/player' */

  });

  return(
    <>
      <Button 
        onClick={() => googleLogin()}
        radius='full' variant='solid' color='indigo' 
      >
        <Text className='text-2xl p-4'>
          Sign in with Google 
        </Text>
      </Button>
    </>
  )
}

export default Login
```

My Backend

```
// backend express

import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import { OAuth2Client, UserRefreshClient } from 'google-auth-library';

const app = express(); 
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const CLIENT_ID = 'my google client id';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'my google client secret';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

// creating the oauth2 client
const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
    CLIENT_ID, // client id
    CLIENT_SECRET, // client secret
    'postmessage',
);

app.post('/auth/google', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Got Request!')
    const { tokens } = await oAuth2Client.getToken(req.body.code); // exchange code for tokens
    console.log(tokens);
    
    res.json(tokens);
});

app.post('/auth/google/refresh-token', async (req, res) => {
    const user = new UserRefreshClient(
        CLIENT_ID,
        CLIENT_SECRET,
        req.body.refreshToken,
    );
    const { credentials } = await user.refreshAccessToken(); // optain new tokens
    res.json(credentials);
}); 


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is Running on port: ${PORT}`);
})
```

I've tried decoding from the backend but it says this:

```
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified".] {  
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

Comment: Okay, after all all i need is to create a const jwtToken = tokens.id_token in the backend server!